# Xml Deserialization does not create any Elements for XmlArray

Tags: c#, wpf, deserialization, indexoutofrangeexception

I am working on a project using WPF and want to Deserialize a XML File with structure like this:

```xml
<SoftwareUpdate>
  <Einträge>
    <Eintrag>
      <Device></Device>
      <language1>
        <Information>
      </language1>
      <language2>
        <Information>
      </language2>
    </Eintrag>
    <Eintrag>
      <Device></Device>
      <language1>
        <Information>
      </language1>
      <language2>
        <Information>
      </language2>
    </Eintrag>
    <Eintrag>
      <Device></Device>
      <language1>
        <Information>
      </language1>
      <language2>
        <Information>
      </language2>
    </Eintrag>    
    <Eintrag>
      <Device></Device>
      <language1>
        <Information>
      </language1>
      <language2>
        <Information>
      </language2>
    </Eintrag>
  <Einträge>
<SoftwareUpdate>
```

these are my classes

```
public class SoftwareUpdate
{
    [XmlElement("Einträge")]
    public Einträge einträge { get; set; }
}

public class Einträge
{
    [XmlArray("Eintrag")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Eintrage", typeof(Eintrag))]
    public Eintrag[] eintrag { get; set; }
}

public class Eintrag
{
    public String Device { get; set; }
    public Language language1 { get; set; }
    public Language language2 { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public String Information { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my Code

```
SoftwareUpdate softwareUpdate = null;
string path = @"C:\XML-File\TestFile.xml";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SoftwareUpdate));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
softwareUpdate = (SoftwareUpdate)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
Trace.WriteLine(softwareUpdate.einträge.Eintrag[1].DeviceType);

reader.Close();
```

But i get `IndexOutOfRangeException` at

```
Trace.WriteLine(softwareUpdate.einträge.Eintrag[1].DeviceType);
```

But the Array `Eintrag` should have four elements. So the problem probably lies somewhere in the code or in the classes but I can't see it.

Comment: Is `ä` a valid character in XML element names?

Comment: Your sample XML is invalid and your sample code doesn't even compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model classes where wrong.

```
public class SoftwareUpdate
{
    [XmlArray("Einträge")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Eintrag", typeof(Eintrag))]
    public Eintrag[] Eintrag { get; set; }
}


public class Eintrag
{
    public String Device { get; set; }
    public Language language1 { get; set; }
    public Language language2 { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public String Information { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look's like a typo in your data model class. It's **Eintrage** instead of **Einträge**

```
public class Einträge
{
    [XmlArray("Eintrag")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Einträge", typeof(Eintrag))]
    public Eintrag[] eintrag { get; set; }
}
```

Anyway I would recomend to use a notation without **'ä'**, better would be  **'ae'**.